# No package 'purple' found

Tags: pidgin, mint, libpurple

I am trying to fix pidgin facebook but i get such an error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (purple <  3) were not met:

No package 'purple' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PURPLE_CFLAGS
and PURPLE_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you install `libpurple-dev`, `libpurple-bin`, etc?

Comment: First try to setup `PPA` https://launchpad.net/~pidgin-developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa and update and install again pidgin.

Comment: I believe that they've stopped support for both the facebook and yahoo account plug-ins.  If everything else works in Pidgin, I'd just remove those two plug-ins.

Comment: @muru purple-dev war required. Thanks